# How can I set 'ulimit -n' permanently? Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, ulimit

I want to set `ulimit -n` permanently.
I've tried with adding this to `/etc/security/limits.conf`

```
*  soft  cpu  nofile 1048576
*  hard  cpu  nofile 1048576
```

and with editing `/proc/sys/fs/file-max`

After restarting Ubuntu both files are still good configured but when I do `ulimit -n` I still get the default limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the `limits.conf` file to be effective, add

```
session required pam_limits.so
```

line to `/etc/pam.d/common-session` and `/etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive` files.